# Hardware specs to optimize Java Programming

Tags: desktop, development

I'm assigned the task to help describing the minimum requirements for hardware used by a Java programming team at my institution.

This team is developing a system that uses about 7 GB RAM when loaded in IDE with one Jboss (yes, Jboss...) instance running. Also, most of them are using Windows 10 OS. This system does not use any machine learning or design tool, meaning that GPUs aren't needed.

My main doubt is related to CPU, since I'm not sure if Java EE compiler can be really affected by frequency or number of cores (I don't think so). The only needs I'm sure are Support for virtualization and support for Dual Channel.

Also, regarding the Disk, I'm not sure if a SSD is something necessary at this point, since the class files are loaded in RAM (Database is hosted on a server).

Therefore, so far I have the minimum RAM requirement at about 12 GB and no need for GPU.

So, to summarize: A Server class (Intel Xeon, for example) or a Many core (12+) CPU will make any difference in this case? Also, is there any important technology that I'm missing?

P.S.: I'm looking for desktops and since it's enterprise environment, closed box first line equipment are the choice, so keep in mind that only things shipped by HP, Dell or Lenovo are considered.

Comment: I have a couple questions. You didn't mention using virtual machines but you say the CPU needs to support virtualization? (The "Java Virtual Machine" does not require CPU virtualization features.) What IDE/Compilers are going to be used? As a programmer myself, an SSD is definitely necessary! It saves me a lot of time with installing software, rebooting the workstation, and compiling large projects.

Comment: They're using IntelliJ, thinking about migrating to Eclipse. Yes, I understand what you said about JVM, however I'm thinking about testing, which may need virtual environments in some cases.

Comment: If they are running VMs *and* that 7 GB development environment I would suggest 16GB of RAM. (5 for headroom & host OS, 4 for guest OS, 7 for dev env). Also, the number of cores in the CPU unfortunately does not scale up Java compilation very well, but multiple independent projects can be compiled in parallel. Your performance gain for compiling on 12 cores vs 8 cores will depend on how your code is organized.